ASP.NET Core Web API on IIS - using TLS 1.2 - but Safari still complains
I have an IIS server (on-premises) which hosts some of my company's internal web sites. Those are mostly ASP.NET Core backends with Angular frontends.
The server machine does have a valid and non-expired certificate, and when I connect with any PC-based browser using the https:// prefix, and check the developer tools, the network shows me that this is a valid TLS 1.2 secured connection.
But for whatever reason, users on Mac using Safari get a big, scary warning message:

This connection is not secure
The security configuration of this website is outdated. .....

and in the details, it goes on:

Safari shows this warning, when a website uses TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1, because those versions are not secure

OK - I do support that statement - BUT my site IS already using TLS 1.2 - so why this scary warning message??
Has anyone else encountered this? Any idea how we can get Mac OS / Safari to SEE that I'm already using TLS 1.2 and stop scaring my users away? Is there anything from a developer point of view in my code that I can do to make these errors go away?
Thanks for any ideas, pointers, hints !

Please involve your network administrators and let them guide you through the troubleshoot. Safari might be right if some device on the wire indeed uses TLS 1.0/1.1, but more data is needed to find the culprit.

@LexLi: does that mean that purely from a developer point of view and in code, I cannot solve this?

You cannot solve a problem before you know enough about it. Thanks.

You can use an SSL testing tool like SSL Labs to see detailed information about your server's SSL/TLS configuration. If possible, test the connection directly from a Mac, using Safari’s developer tools to inspect the warning and the SSL/TLS connection details.

Could you check http version through browser developer tools? If IIS application requires SSL AND "Client Certificates" settings is not set as "Ignored" then IIS reverts back to http v1.1 even if your application does not use Windows Authentication. In short "Windows Authentication" or  "Client Certificate Authentication"  makes IIS revert back to http v1.1 from http/2.  Http version changes might affect TLS versions. curl.exe and invoke-webrequest tools have options to force different TLS versions with different agent types (Mozilla, Safari etc), so the warning reason may be clearer.
